# Custom Content-Type in HTTP POST request?

Tags: http, http-headers

I have a custom data format that I'm sending in an HTTP post body. I'm wondering if I should use `text/plain` or `application/octet-stream`, or if I could use a custom `Content-Type`? Is making it custom in bad taste?

The format looks like this:

```
test0,id=28084 type=high,18765003 138456387
```

Comment: Looks like plain text to me, hence `text/plain` would seem appropriate.  No need to complicate things with custom mime types (which may need to be explicitly added to your web host).  Octet-stream is usually for binary data

Comment: @Martin by that logic application/json is also text. It is, but it's not best to use `text/plain`

Comment: @Evert Can you explain why "_it's not best to use_ `text/plain`"?  For the life of me I can't figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good idea to use a custom mime type.

If the name of your product is 'sally', you might for example use:

```
application/prs.sally.testresults
application/vnd.sally.testresults
text/prs.sally.testresults
text/vnd.sally.testresults
application/x.sally.testresults
application/x.sally.testresults
text/x.sally.testresults
text/x.sally.testresults
```

The `prs` stands for 'personal', `vnd` stands for 'vendor', and `x` stands for unregistered.

You're officially required to register your `prs` or `vnd` mimetypes, but frankly very few do and it doesn't matter *that* much as long as you make an effort to make it reasonably unique.

The difference between `application` and `text` can be pretty subtle, because things like JSON and Javascript also use `application`.

Generally using `application` means intermediates like proxies will never try to automatically change things like character encoding, whereas `text` they might.

If something is more like a computer-interpreted format I would probably prefer `application`, and if it's more intended as human-readable text, then `text` is probably the right move.

Comment: Isn't the `vnd` prefix for vendor-specific types that have already been registered with IANA?

Comment: @Martin, yes this was mentioned